# backbone view and router - view instanciated multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following router
var watchlistEditView = new WatchlistEditView({ });

```
router.on('route:editWatchlist', function(id) {
    console.log("routing to editWachlist");
    console.log(id);

    var watchlistEditView = new WatchlistEditView({ });
    watchlistEditView.render({id: id});
});
```

I do notice that I have multiple instances of the view so when I perform an operation, it does trigger on every instances, which is not what I want.

Is it ok to create the new view each time the router get called?
How could I prevent the view to get instanciated multiple times?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is something to make a good research as it involves many things. Memory management, listener bindings and things that actually backbone is handling every moment you create and destroy a view.
I recommend reading this article.

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Actually I create and destroy what I need using backbone marionette framework and behind the scenes when working on layouts and backbone views it makes several checks as if the view is rendered if I am adding a new view to a region with a view already, and other things.

I recommend keep on creating them, and looking when to destroy them when it is necessary.

Comment: For instance every time you create a listener from a view to a model you are actually binding something, that when you destroy the view you just stop listening, you dont want to handle those things by yourself